# Ems or pixels in fluid layouts?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a new web page that should work on different devices and I am using fluid layout. Should I use pixels or ems in fluid layouts for font size? And what about paddings etc?

Comment: Use whatever you feel most naturally to you, as long as you use media query this shouldn't be a problem. A good example is Twitter Bootstrap. They use pixels with fluid layouts.

Comment: This article is very good for explaining this whole topic, especially if you get to the bottom. And instead of recommending em's, it recommends rem's. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: @Caelea Twitter is a pretty good example if you want to show how to do things wrong.  Using specific font sizes only serves to reduce usability for users who may have adjusted their browser's default font-size to something they can read.  "Just use what's natural for you" is a cop out for people who don't care to do what's best for the user.

Answer (score 2):

For fluid layouts you will want to use percentages. Pixels are relative to a monitors resolution and EMs are relative the the font-size and pixel density. Percentages, however, are relative to the size of the window in which they are placed (or their parent's width). For that reason, it is the best option for fluidity. Your padding can also be percentages, just keep in mind that the values are relative so it can get tricky with spacing things equidistant.

For fonts, ems are perfectly acceptable since they are based on the font itself. Also, by using ems for fonts, you allow yourself to scale the font for the entire site just by changing the documents font size.

Comment: *"Pixels are relative to a monitors resolution"*... OK what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it but, in the context of fluid layouts, you cannot define fluidity in pixels - you can with percentages. Fixed-width layouts are more where pixels shine (or responsive layouts with breakpoints).

Comment: It really depends what the OP means. Of course defining column widths in pixels is only for fixed-width layouts, but defining padding and things like that - it doesn't matter. Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: Oh, for **font size**. I missed that. In that case I still suggest that it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 2):

If you use em's you can use css media queries for different device widths.

Using px on the body font size and em's on everything else means all font sizes will be relative to the body. You can then include media queries that just increase or decrease the body font size, and all other font sizes will change relative to it.

You can also then include web accessibility buttons that increase font size for those with visual impairments. The button would also just change the body font size (again changing all other fonts relative to it).

Em's all the way!

(Extra edit)
Also if you're thinking about font size in depth, you could also consider vertical rhythm/baseline for your site. Check out these links:

http://alistapart.com/article/settingtypeontheweb

http://typecast.com/blog/4-simple-steps-to-vertical-rhythm

Setting px for the body, then em for all other font-size, line-height, margins etc. will enable you create fluid designs whilst maintaining the vetical rhythm. Badass.

Answer (score 0):

I find 'ems' are better to use in a fluid layout or any layout for that matter.